# Main thread wait for detached thread to complete in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I want to start two child threads in `main()`. But I want the main function to wait until them have finished and then stop. Otherwise, the variables in child threads will be cleaned and errors happen.

My code is as below:

```
void textWorker(char* str, int len);
void imageWorker(char* imagepath);

int worker(char* my_str, char* path){
    std::thread t1(textWorker, my_str, length);
    t1.detach();
    std::thread t2(imageWorker, path);
    t2.detach();
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    char* my_str, path;
    ...
    worker(my_str, path);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Currently, the main thread will stop very soon while `t1` and `t2` will cost a few seconds. And `my_str` will be cleaned and `textWorker` will operate on random characters (similar case for `imageWorker` and `path`).

I need to wrap the major work in a function (i.e. `worker()`) which can be called by 3rd party. How can I correct my codes to match my purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you do realize that `std::thread::detach` do exactly the oposit of what you want?
you need to `join` them to get the affect:

```
int worker(char* my_str, char* path){
    std::thread t1(textWorker, my_str, length);
    std::thread t2(imageWorker, path);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: they are doing it     .

Comment: Umm...Okay, I've mistaken the sequence of constructor and join() calling...Your code works.

Comment: time threshold...no worry.

Answer (score 0):

A `condition_variable` will help you do what you want.

The [en.cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) has a good example that does what you want to do.